# How to write text inside a graphic using shiny::HTML() function?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to write text inside a `plot` function in `R` with a `shiny::HTML` function.

But I couldn't do that inside the `graphics::text` function:

My shinyApp:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard", titleWidth = 300)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 300, 
                        
                        sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                    
                                    menuItem(text = "Plot", tabName = "plot", icon = icon("chart-pie")) 
                                    
                        )
)

body <- dashboardBody(

  tabItem(tabName = "plot",
      
      fluidPage(
        
        column(width = 12, 
               
               box(plotOutput(outputId = "plot1", click = "plot_click"), width = 6, title = 
                     "Gráfico 1")
               
        ) 
      )
  )

)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "blue")

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    plot(x = .5, y = .5)

    graphics::text(
      x = .5, y = .5, cex = 1.8,
  
      HTML("<p> First line;<br>
      Second line;<br>
      Third line.</p>")
    
    )

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But:

[image]

Function does not work (HTML tags are not recognized).

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is modified based on your requirement for HTML. This works. There is probably a better way to do this, though.

In the `dashboardbody(fluidpage())` I add tag rules. Additionally, the text for the plot is there as well. You can write whatever HTML you would like there. Currently, it is set to the center of the plot (roughly). The text starts at the halfway point vertically and the halfway point from the right (so it is off-center). You can adjust the percentages in `top: 50%;` and `right: 50%;` to move it around. Stay with percentages, that way as the view screen size changes, it stays in the same relative position.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard", titleWidth = 300)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 300, 
                            sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                        menuItem(text = "Plot", 
                                                 tabName = "plot", 
                                                 icon = icon("chart-pie")) 
                            )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItem(tabName = "plot",
          fluidPage(
            tags$head(
              tags$style(HTML("
                    .col-sm-12 {
                      position: relative;
                      display: block;
                      height: 100%;
                      width: 100%;
                    }
                    .col-sm-6, 
                    .box, 
                    .box div div img,
                    .col-sm-12 .col-sm-6 + div{
                      width: 100%;
                      height: 100%;
                      top: 0;
                      left: 0;
                    }
                    .col-sm-12 .col-sm-6 + div span {
                      margin: 0;
                      top: 50%;
                      right: 50%;
                      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
                      -transform:translateY(-50%);
                      z-index: 9;
                      position: absolute;
                    }
                    "))
            ),
            column(width = 12, 
                   box(width = 6, title = "Gráfico 1",
                       plotOutput(outputId = "plot1", 
                                  click = "plot_click")),
                   div(HTML("<span>First line;<br>Second line;<br>Third line.</span>"))
            ) 
          )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "blue")

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(x = .5, y = .5)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I need to use the `shiny::HTML` function to edit my text better. I use `graphics::text` because I'm using `golem` framework.

Comment: You may be able to overlay the text on the plot using HTML and CSS's z-index if you require HTML.

Comment: How can I do this?